# What is the thing you do to space apart images?

Tags: html, css

I tried everything but nothing works?

[emphasized text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEamE.png)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose, both images are under the same element, so what you can do, is add css to your parent element:

```js
display: flex;
gap: 10px
```

or you can choose one of the images and add css:

```js
margin-left: 10px
```

or

```js
margin-right: 10px
```